# Openconnect won't connect in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, vpn, openconnect

I have been having some problems with `openconnect` in my Arch Linux (Antergos to be precise) and I have no idea what's causing it. (Although I'm used to linux and all, I'm very new to VPNs and `openconnect`.)

I'm trying to connect to my University's VPN via 2 methods. I start by following the instructions, which simply say to create a Cisco AnyConnect Compatible VPN and input the name and gateway.

When I do it this way and try to connect via the network-manager applet it doesn't work. When I flip the VPN switch it simply flips right back immediately and that's it. No error messages or anything.

The second approach I'm trying is via command line. So I try this

```
$ sudo openconnect -u myusername my.gateway.edu
```

*(I'm replacing the actual gateway with `my.gateway.edu` and also the username and blurring relevant IPs from now on)*

This is the log I get from that input:

```
POST https://my.gateway.edu/
Connected to 164.**.**.**:443
SSL negotiation with my.gateway.edu
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found

Certificate from VPN server "my.gateway.edu" failed verification.
Reason: signer not found
To trust this server in future, perhaps add this to your command line:
    --servercert sha256:bb2476a96b88357fe74f28a347ba549a2af4bea8668e30a77e1a8295f466bfdc
Enter 'yes' to accept, 'no' to abort; anything else to view: yes
Connected to HTTPS on my.gateway.edu
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Error generating GSSAPI response:
gss_init_sec_context(): Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
gss_init_sec_context(): SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate
Server 'my.gateway.edu' requested Basic authentication which is disabled by default
GET https://my.gateway.edu/
Connected to 164.**.**.**:443
SSL negotiation with my.gateway.edu
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
Connected to HTTPS on my.gateway.edu
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
No more authentication methods to try
GET https://my.gateway.edu/
Please enter your username.
POST https://my.gateway.edu/auth
Please enter your password.
Password:
POST https://my.gateway.edu/auth
Got CONNECT response: HTTP/1.1 200 CONNECTED
CSTP connected. DPD 90, Keepalive 32400
Connected as 169.**.***.**, using SSL
DTLS handshake failed: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again.
Failed to open tun device: No such device
Set up tun device failed
Unknown error; exiting.
```

I have asked the University's IT support but they also don't know what's happening (I think they're not very familiar with Arch Linux). I have tried some other things such as using the flag `--script /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script` but the result is the same.

**EDIT**

I have recently come across [this website](https://medium.com/@v4runvs/using-openconnect-instead-of-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-agent-d7bc7d9b1631) via the IT people that says that I have to create a tunnel device before connecting. Even after doing that the results of `sudo openconnect -u myusername my.gateway.edu --interface tun1` are still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I created a tunnel device using [this link](https://medium.com/@v4runvs/using-openconnect-instead-of-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-agent-d7bc7d9b1631) the CLI approach worked, even though the GUI approach still failed. I also installed `networkmanager-vpnc` through pacman, but I don't think that is related to anything.

I also found out through the IT people that adding the `--http-auth=Basic` flag gets rid of some the errors. It's worth noting that even after all this I still get a `DTLS handshake failed`, even though I can connect to the servers I need to.

Answer (score 7):

I just had this problem. [The other solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412617/106752) didn't work for me, but after a bit of Googling, I found [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=163377) which explains/hypothesize that the issue has been caused by `pacman -Syu` which has caused the kernel to be updated and as the result, there are some mismatch things which can be solved by simply **restarting the computer**. The good old "turning it off and on again"!

Comment: Rebooting indeed worked for me...!